# View pdf stream in browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a PDF file that I want to view in browser tab. I know that I can use file link directly to display it, but I want to read contents of file in a variable and use the variable to display file. Reason behind is, I want to delete the file immediately after reading in variable.

PHP:

```
$fdata = file_get_contents($tmppdf);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=".$tmppdf);
return $fdata;
```

Ajax:

```
$('body').on('click', '.printInvoice', function () {
     var purchase_id = $(this).data("id");
     // window.location.href = "/purchases/print" + '/' + purchase_id;
     window.open('/purchases/print' + '/' + purchase_id, '_blank');
});
```

I am getting binary contents in result. Can someone help, what is wrong with my code.

[image]

UPDATE :
Changed my ajax code to below and now I am getting a blank pdf page

```
$('body').on('click', '.printInvoice', function () {
   var purchase_id = $(this).data("id");
   $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "/purchases/print" + '/' + purchase_id,
     success: function (data) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(blobURL,'_blank');
        },
     error: function (data) {
        alert("Unable to Print !!!");
        }
});
```

Comment: Are you returning that php code from a controller function?

Comment: yes, it is a laravel 5.8 controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
return Response::make($fdata, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$tmppdf.'"'
]);
```

Comment: Can you help how can I convert it to an Ajax Success call.  As mentioned in Update of my question; I tried to put "window.open(data,'_blank');" in the Success portion, but I get a blank page in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel actually has built-in functionality to return [file responses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/responses#file-responses). This will automatically set the correct headers so the file gets displayed in the browser.

```
return response()->file($tmppdf);
```

Comment: It works but does not solve my problem, because it loads from file, and I cannot delete the file. I want to load file contents to a variable and delete the file.

Comment: Why don't you first store the response of `response()->file($tmppdf)`, then delete the file, then return the response you already stored?
e.g. `$fileResponse = response()->file($tmppdf); /* code to delete file goes here */ return $fileResponse;`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stream the file you can use this to display the file:

This worked with a binary string.

```
return Response::make($file, 200, [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
]);
```